# OpenSSL upgrade - CentOS 7

Tags: apache, openssl, centos7

I have a CentOS 7 installation running httpd-2.4.35 and openssl-1.0.2k, but due to vulnerability findings, I need to update OpenSSL to at lease 1.0.2s, preferably u. Unfortunately, I cannot find RPM for these packages, which would make it a lot simpler.
I have tried to upgrade the using the tarball provided by OpenSSL but, although the installation works, httpd still uses Openssl-1.0.2k. It seems that I am not doing all the actions that the RPM installation is doing. Does anyone know if I can find this newer OpenSSL1.0.2 RPM packages somewhere or how to force httpd (installed via RPM) to use another version of OpenSSL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using OpenSSL 1.0.2k from the RPM package provided by CentOS 7, you are going to receive OpenSSL security updates via `yum update` until [June 2024](https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/errata#Life_Cycle_Dates). Red Hat with RHEL 7, upstream of CentOS 7, is [backporting security fixes](https://access.redhat.com/security/updates/backporting). This means that there is no rebase to a new version such as 1.0.2s, but 1.0.2k will get a patch added resolving the security flaw. A recently active [Red Hat community discussion](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/4285911) is covering almost the same topic and referring to the same explanation.

Unfortunately you are not referring to a specific security flaw to provide a specific example. If you would like to know which RPM package fixes CVE-2020-1971, you can visit https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/cve-2020-1971 and figure out there, that errata [RHSA-2020:5566](https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2020:5566) contains the fix, thus RPM package "openssl-1.0.2k-**21**.el7_9". And if you are e.g. on "openssl-1.0.2k-**19**.el7" (which can be figured out using e.g. `rpm -q openssl`), this indeed means you should apply updates using `yum update`.